# Compatibility of a Sigma Lens adapted to a Minolta 7000 A/F camera with a Sony Alpha 330 Camera

Tags: lens, sony, sigma

I have a Minolta 7000 A/F film camera, circa 1986. I also have a Sigma 75-300 A/F Lens which works well with that camera.

I have since updated to the Sony Alpha 330 camera and the original Minolta lenses work well with it, including A/F; but the Sigma lens doesn't work at all. Is it possible to have the electronics of the Sigma lens updated and, if so, at what cost?

Comment: I don't know why it would not work. Unlike brands like Canon, the Minolta (and compatible) lenses are completely passive - no electronics inside at all. I have a Sony A57 that works just fine with my Tamron 28-300 A/F. It also works with my Minolta 7000i and Minolta 5D (digital) cameras. Does the Sigma still work with the 7000?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but Sigma doesn't offer chip upgrades for such an old lenses anymore.

I don't know which exact version you have, but if it's Sigma 75-300 F4-5.6 DL Zoom or Sigma 75-300 F4.5-5.6 APO, in theory it should work with your A330. I'd suspect hardware damage, though there's hardly anything you can do with that anymore.

I'd suggest buying new Sigma 70-300 f/4-5.6 APO DG Macro, as it's roughly the cheapest lens from these that are "*good enough*" to bother. ;) Alternative would be Tamron SP 70-300mm F 4-5.6 Di USD - I got that one, and in it's own price-point it's really the best thing on the market, regardless of they bayonet.